# tensorflow Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array. Tflite

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a network(git link below) and saved in the  saved model format. And would like to convert it to tflite. I am using python API for tflite coverter(`tflite.py` in git link below). But I'am not able to do so.

System information:
**OS Platform and Distribution:** Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
**TensorFlow version:** tensorflow/tensorflow:2.2.0-gpu  (docker)

[The link](https://github.com/uidchet/tflite-issue) to network and save model code.

The output from the converter invocation:

```
File "tflite.py", line 22, in convert_model
  tflite_model = converter.convert()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 459, in convert
  self._funcs[0], lower_control_flow=False))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 706, in convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph
  func, lower_control_flow, aggressive_inlining)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 457, in _convert_variables_to_constants_v2_impl
  tensor_data = _get_tensor_data(func)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py", line 217, in _get_tensor_data
  data = val_tensor.numpy()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 961, in numpy
  maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 929, in _numpy
  six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot convert a Tensor of dtype resource to a NumPy array.
```

[The link](https://github.com/uidchet/tflite-issue/blob/master/sav_model.zip) to the saved model

Comment: Looks like you have used distribution strategy. I am not sure whether it is supported or not. However, I have tried many models without distribution strategy and with saved_model, everything works.

Comment: Yes ,to clarify with out distribution it works for me as well. Have any ideas to get it working for mirrored strategy?